# Fix threaded comments

Tags: themes, comment-form

http://anasianscreations.co.cc/jeffman/blog/uncategorized/hello-world/

I have looked all day for a solution but whenever you click on reply to this comment, instead of the comment box being displayed underneath you are redirected to the anchor.

Also when I am in this theme, and you reply to a post, it does not register as a reply to a reply, instead it is just a regular reply.

There is no doubt that I have missed something, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the comment reply Javascript being enqueued.

Add this to your header, just before the wp_head() call:

```
if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
```

Comment: I added the comment-reply script but the comment form is still not being moved to the correct place.

Comment: It works on your site now for me. When I click reply to comment, the reply box appears right there.

Comment: I checked again and it works. Hm, I must have been seeing something on my part. Thank you.